# git old branches not cleaned up in local repo

Tags: git

we are using git on linux
sometimes branches get created for modifs to be tested
and we retrieve these branches to our local system
now the branch gets merged and in webinterface, the branch is not visible anymore
in my local system i executed git pull / git fetch / git remote prune origin from main branch
but when executing git branch --list - I still see a branch that is not existing in webinterface anymore.
anything missing or doing wrong ?
thanks for all help
best regards, Guy

Comment: Each repository has *its own* branch names. Just as Fred (Abrams) isn't Fred (Barkley), branch `zog` in the repository on Fred Abrams' machine is not the same `zog` as the branch named `zog` in the repository on Fred Barkley's machine. Fred and Fred are different people, and zog and zog are different branches. If Fred wants to delete zog, Fred should delete zog. (That goes for both Freds and both zogs.)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want `git fetch` to locally remove branches that were removed on the remote site, you can use:

[Git - git-fetch Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt--p)

> -p
> --prune
>
> Before fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote. Tags are not subject to pruning if they are fetched only because of the default tag auto-following or due to a --tags option. However, if tags are fetched due to an explicit refspec (either on the command line or in the remote configuration, for example if the remote was cloned with the --mirror option), then they are also subject to pruning. Supplying `--prune-tags` is a shorthand for providing the tag refspec.

Comment: I did execute the  command but did not resolve the problem     I executed  :[dbadmin@luechdb61 db2-setup]$ git branch --list
  machine_process_end_blob_separation
* main
  retype_serial_number
on the remote repos the retype_serial_number is not  present anymore only the machine...  and when executing git fetch --prune, just prompted for password and no additional messgae   best regards, Guy